# Variable inside a foreach loop with PHP and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to add some UUID's to my users table. I'm having a foreach loop which should generate a unique UUID for every user in my db. The problem is that every user is getting the same UUID in the db, but when I add a "echo" i see that it generates a separate UUID for every user, but that is not reflected in the db. Is PDO doing some sort of caching, as it doesn't care about that the $uuid variable is changing?

```
function getAllIds($db) {
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT id from users;");
$array = $stmt->fetchAll();
return $array;
}

foreach (getAllIds($db) as $ids) {
$uuid = uuid();
print "$uuid\n";
$stmt = $db->prepare("update users set user_uuid = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($uuid));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a user id on the where clause:

```
function getAllIds($db) {
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT id from users;");
    $array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $array;
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET user_uuid = :uuid WHERE id = :id");
$ids = getAllIds($db);
foreach ($ids as $k => $id) {
    $uuid = uuid();
    $stmt->execute(array(':uuid' => $uuid, ':id' => $id['id']));
}
```

Comment: Why `$ids[$k]` instead of `$id`? Isn't that the point of using `foreach` rather than `for`?

Comment: @ghost I have tried your solution, but I am getting a "Array to string conversion..." error

Comment: @TheG oh i forgot, this is a multi dimensional, check my revision

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are always updating the id of *all* entries inside your foreach loop. So when the fooreach loop has finished, all entries in the database will have the last chosen uuid as id.

Instead you must make sure to only modify a single database entry with each run of the loop. You can do that by specifying the entries in inside a where clause to the update statement.

```
$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET user_uuid=:uuid WHERE id=:id");
foreach (getAllIds($db) as $entry)
  $query->execute(array(':uuid'=>uuid(), ':id'=>$entry['id']));
```

A side aspect: you should prepare that update statement only once: before the foreach loop. No need to repeat that step with every run.

Comment: You are absolutely right about preparing the statement before the loop.